# Reprocessing processing

Tags: discussion, tag-cleanup-request

[processing](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/processing) is used in two ways - firstly as a meta-tag. Secondly to do with the processing language/IDE.

I'd propose killing off the processing tag and merging it with a tag that specifically denotes the language - either [processing-ide](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/processing-ide) looks good to me, since it its a *language* issue, it dosen't belong here.

Comment: what about combining [tag:image] [tag:processing] to [tag:image-processing].. then again [tag:image-processing] doesn't have high quality questions..

Comment: I'd just remove the processing tag there, and replace them with tool specific tags. Then leave [tag:image-processing] for another day